# error: package android.support.constraint does not exist

Tags: android, androidx

In Android studio with java, I'm trying to use material calendar to add data range marker to my Android app. After adding some features to use material calendar, I got this error.

```
"error: package android.support.constraint does not exist".
```

this is where the error occured: `FragmentFirstBinding.java`(and this file is not able to modify)

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.example.endurence.databinding;

**import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;**
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBindings;
import com.example.endurence.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;
```

this is the `build.gradle(:app)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.endurence"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

this is the `settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Endurence"
include ':app'
```

and this is the `gradle.properties`

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

add) this is `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#292929">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/nnn_head"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_img" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeSinceLastSnow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="@string/time_since_last_snow"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_box"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/topLinearLayout"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/averageSnowCycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/average_snow_cycle"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_box"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/timeSinceLastSnow"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastSnowDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/averageSnowCycle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_box"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/last_snow_date"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lastSnowDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
        app:mcv_selectionMode="range"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
        app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="sunday"
        app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
        app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tryed android(before migrate to androidx) and androidx both and still the error came out.
I changed all the dependecies version to the latest version with google's maven repository.
I tried Build > Clean Project and Build > Rebuild Project
I tried Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart.
(I tried almost everything what GPT4 and internet recommended-actually I couldn't find similar error from internet btw nothing worked

Comment: Can you share the XML file where you use the constraint layout?

Comment: I added activity_main.xml, where I placed the calendar.
If that's the error about xmls, there will be the error since that's the only xml I edited

Comment: What is the layout inside MaterialCalendarView? Could there be a constraint layout there?

Comment: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/MaterialCalendarView.java

I think this is what I called at my xml but I'm not sure there is any constraint layout thing

Comment: Doesn't seem like it uses constraint layout (https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/calendar_view.xml). Did you search your project for it's usage? Could be caused by another dependency.